# How to solve race condition?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, race-condition

Value of Global variable `var` in `main()` function sometimes comes -1 and sometimes 1 .How to write a robust code without using sleep function so that thread get time to get started and running .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int var = -1; // GLobal Variable
  
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    var = 1;
    return NULL;
}
   
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);

    printf("var=%d",var);

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Just FYI: POSIX Threads are not Linux-specific.

Comment: `sleep()` is a timing function, not a synchronization function. It has no place whatever in managing inter-thread action.  Use a proper synchronization if robustness is really what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Value of Global variable `var` in `main()` function sometimes comes -1 and
> sometimes 1 .How to write a robust code without using sleep function
> so that thread get time to get started and running .

It is a distressingly common misconception among those new to multithreaded programming that problems such as yours are a matter of *timing*.  That is not the case, at least not from the perspective of the threading and memory models of most modern high-level programming languages.  No amount of delay alone ensures that one thread will see the effects on memory produced by another, therefore robust code does not use timing functions such as `sleep()` for that purpose.

Rather, the issue is one of *synchronization*.  This is the area that contains rules about what writes to memory by one thread must be visible to other threads.  It also covers special kinds of objects and functions that serve to enable threads to affect the execution of other threads, generally by temporarily blocking them from proceeding.  These two facets are closely linked.

The `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()` functions have synchronization effects.  Among other things, all writes to memory by a thread T1 before it calls `pthread_create()` to start a thread T2 are visible to T2 (modulo subsequent rewrites of the same memory).  All writes to memory by T2 are visible to T1 after it successfully joins T2 via `pthread_join()`.  Therefore, one solution to the question as posed is to wait until after joining the second thread before attempting to read `var`, as [@Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68494215/2402272) suggests.

If that is undesirable, then you'll need to engage some other kind of synchronization mechanism to make the main thread wait for the second to update `var`.  Such a wait on a synchronization object will also have the effect of making the second thread's write visible to the main thread.

The most general-purpose synchronization technique offered by pthreads is the *condition variable* which must be used in conjunction with a *mutex*.  You will find many explanations here on SO and elsewhere about how properly to use a CV.

For your particular case, however, you might find a semaphore easier to set up and use.  Semaphores are technically separate from the pthreads library proper, but they have suitable synchronization semantics, both for making threads wait and for making memory operations of one thread visible to another.  That might look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

int var = -1; // GLobal Variable
sem_t semaphore;
  
void *myThreadFun(void *vargp)
{
    var = 1;

    // increment the semaphore's value
    sem_post(&semaphore);

    return NULL;
}
   
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;

    // initialize the semaphore with value 0
    sem_init(&semaphore, 0, 0);

    printf("Before Thread\n");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);

    // Wait until the semaphore's value can be decremented by one without
    // it becoming negative (and then perform the decrement before proceeding).
    sem_wait(&semaphore);

    printf("var=%d",var);

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is robust, it's just where you `print` the result which is incorrect. You need to ensure your thread has finished his work before printing the result.

If you `print` the result before calling `pthread_join`, there are two possibilities:

- myThreadFun has already changed `var`, in such case `var` will contain the value `1`
- myThreadFun hasn't been completely executed, in such case, `var` will have its initial value `-1`.

If you `print` the result after calling `pthread_join`, the function `myThreadFun` will be fully executed and it will print `1`.

```
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread_id;
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");

    printf("var=%d",var); /* Here, the thread has completed */

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: issue there are 100s of line of code between pthread_create and pthread_join , so can't move it below as you did

Comment: what tools are available to get var value updated by thread without adding a sleep

Comment: There is `pthread_join` to wait for thread termination. You could also use `pthread_cond_wait()` to wait for what is called `condition variable` to change its value.

Comment: In a nutshell , my question is how to wait for thread to get started

Comment: Then you could go for `ikegami` solution or look for `pthread_cond_wait`.

Answer (score -1):

Robert's solution is sensible, but I believe you don't actually want to wait for the thread to complete.

If you want the main thread to wait for the variable to be set by the thread without waiting for the thread to end, you will need some kind of synchronization. I'll use a semaphore, but there are a number of other solutions.

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static sem_t started_threads_sem;
static int var;

static void *myThreadFun(void *vargp) {
    sleep(3);  // This is the thread doing some initialization.

    var = 1;
    sem_post(&started_threads_sem);

    sleep(3);  // This is the thread doing stuff.

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    printf("Before Thread\n");
    sem_init(&started_threads_sem, 0, 0);

    pthread_t thread_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, myThreadFun, NULL);

    // Wait for the thread to have started.
    sem_wait(&started_threads_sem);
    printf("var=%d\n", var);

    pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
    printf("After Thread\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

```
Before Thread
<3 s pause>
var=1
<3 s pause>
After Thread
```